# How io invoke member if member has callback implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, duplex-channel

I have a service object which has method having callback implementation mentioned below

```
public string GetMacName()
{
string value = System.Environment.MachineName.ToString();
msgCallback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallBack>();
 msgCallback.Notify(value);
return value;
}
```

I have created a DuplexChannelfactory and got the service object in my client. Now, with the service object I retrieve Type as
Client Side:

```
DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceOne> factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceOne>(callbackInstance, new NetTcpBinding(), "uri");
proxyObject = factory.CreateChannel(); Type t=  proxyObject.GetType();
```

I have implemented IServiceOneCallback method in client

```
public string Notify(string value)
{
Notification=value;
}
```

I am invoking the method GetMacName() as mentioned below:

```
t.Invoke("GetMacName", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, proxyObject, args);
```

this is getting failed... where i m wrong,is something for callback needs to done in Invoke

Comment: Why can't you call proxyObject.GetMacName()?

Comment: Add the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: actually that is the requirement, i need to pass the method name and invoke from the object dynamically, strangely i have created a created a separate project and there it is working.... same code... Thanks for the input, need to check where is the problem. :(

Comment: Got it working...  [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,UseSynchronizationContext=false)] attribute needs to be added for wpf or winform application, something to do with synchronization context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working... [CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,UseSynchronizationCon‌​text=false)] attribute needs to be added for wpf or winform application, something to do with synchronization context. Thank you for your inputs.